# Tabulator-tables 5.4 date sorter not working

Tags: angular, typescript, tabulator

I'm trying to implement tabular-tables 5.4 into application.
Currently using example from: http://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/sort#sorter-date
Currently table is running, and other sorters are working fine, but date doesn't want to cooperate...
there is an error in console

```
RROR ReferenceError: luxon is not defined
    at Sort.datetime$2 (tabulator_esm.js:18666:1)
    at Sort.date$1 (tabulator_esm.js:18715:1)
    at Sort._sortRow (tabulator_esm.js:19312:1)
    at tabulator_esm.js:19284:1
    at Array.sort (<anonymous>)
    at Sort._sortItems (tabulator_esm.js:19278:1)
    at Sort.sort (tabulator_esm.js:19219:1)
    at RowManager.refreshPipelines (tabulator_esm.js:22880:1)
    at VirtualDomVertical.rerenderRows (tabulator_esm.js:21702:1)
    at RowManager.reRenderInPosition (tabulator_esm.js:23007:1)
```

those are imports to component:

```
import {Tabulator, PageModule, FormatModule, InteractionModule, EditModule, SortModule} from 'tabulator-tables';

Tabulator.registerModule([FormatModule, PageModule, InteractionModule,EditModule,SortModule]);
```

this is html:

```
<div id="example-table"></div>
```

this is table data

```
tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"21", col:"red", dob: "", state: true},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", state: true},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982", state: false},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980", state: false},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999", state: true},
  ];
```

this is table def:

```
let table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
     // height: 205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
      data: this.tabledata, //assign data to table
      layout: "fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
      pagination: "local",
      paginationSize: 6,
      paginationSizeSelector: [1, 2, 4, 8],
      paginationCounter: "rows",
      columns: [ //Define Table Columns
        {title: "Name", field: "name", width: 150},
        {title: "Age", field: "age", hozAlign: "left",sorter:"number", sorterParams:{
            alignEmptyValues:"top",
          }},
        {title: "Favourite Color", field: "col", sorter: "alphanum"},
        {title: "Date Of Birth", field: "dob", sorter:"date",sorterParams:{
            alignEmptyValues:"top",
          }},
        {title: "Toggle", field: "state", formatter: "tickCross", formatterParams: {
            allowEmpty: true,
            allowTruthy: true,
            tickElement: "<i class='fa-solid fa-toggle-on' style='color:green'></i>",
            crossElement: "<i class='fa-solid fa-toggle-off' style='color:red'></i>",
          },
          cellClick:function(e, cell){console.log(`cell ${cell.getValue()}`)
            console.log(`e`)
        }
        }
      ],

    });
```

I've added luxon but as you can see above it is not recognized, so I think my question would be, how to add it correctly:
package.json

```
 "@types/luxon": "^3.0.1",
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq4PQ.png)

On http://tabulator.info/ all examples are for javascript, so maybe there is something I should do differently for typescript?

Answer (score 0):

So... I managed to install luxon propperly by
this was missing step

```
yarn add luxon
```

and

```
yarn add @types/luxon
```

So now I'm able to use luxon in component after

```
import {DateTime} from 'luxon'
...
console.log( DateTime.local())
```

and this is result

```
DateTime {ts: 1665123645984, _zone: SystemZone, loc: Locale, invalid: null, weekData: null, …}
```

So it looks like Tabular-tables doesn't see luxon but don't know why...